# Elastic beanstalk deployment taking longer than timeout period, how do I increase timeout period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk deployment of a new environment for an application using the AWS website warns

```
Create environment operation is complete, but with command timeouts. Try increasing the timeout period
```

and although it eventually shows environment as green trying to connect to the url just gives

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

An earlier version of the application works fine, but in the ebextensions it has to copy a large file from s3 and then unzip it, this takes quite a while. The earlier version of the application only has to copy a 3GB file but the new version has to copy a 6GB file and as I can see no other errors Im guessing this has caused the timeout and prevented tomcat starting.

But how do I increase the timeout,  I cannot see where I am meant to do it ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using option settings. Option settings can be specified using ebextensions.

Create a file in your app source in a directory called `.ebextensions`. Lets say the file is `.ebextensions/01-increase-timeout.config`.

The contents of the file should be:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000
```

Note this file is in YAML format.
After this you can update your environment with this version of source code.

From documentation for this option setting:

> Timeout: Number of seconds to wait for an instance to complete
>   executing commands.
>
> For example, if source code deployment tasks are still running when you reach the configured timeout period, AWS Elastic Beanstalk
>   displays the following error: "Some instances have not responded to
>   commands. Responses were not received from ." You can
>   increase the amount of time that the AWS Elastic Beanstalk service
>   waits for your source code to successfully deploy to the instance.

You can read more about ebextensions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html). Documentation on option settings is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html).

Comment: Great that fixes it, FWIW I originally set value to 2000 but the max value allowed is 1800 (1/2 hour), thats okay because it only takes 11 minutes to deploy on the instance I i used but surprised the max value was that low.

Comment: I got yaml syntax error from aws, then I remove the spaces (yaml validator instruct me): option_name:Timeout and value:1000 (no spaces after the ":"). now its works great. thanks!

Comment: Do NOT follow @dang advice! you need a space between value: and number. Correct is: `value: 1000`.  not `value:1000`

Comment: @Roman you dont need to be rude. it did not succeed for me with the spaces so i removed them and now its ok for me. I did not advice nothing just point out some problem I encounter maybe it will help others if they encounter the same problem.

Comment: do I need to add reference of this file somewhere in project ?
I'm getting "ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is unknown. The timeout can be set using the --timeout option."

Answer (score 7):

Use: --timeout

For eg: `eb create -db --timeout 20`

This will give you 20 minutes of timeout limit.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) you can pass `--timeout` option to your `eb create` call.

```
--timeout minutes
Set number of minutes before the command times out.
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the same timeout? Or is this the timeout for the eb-cli itself? My eb cli times out with `ERROR: TimeoutError - The EB CLI timed out after 10 minute(s). The operation might still be running. To keep viewing events, run 'eb events -f'. To set timeout duration, use '--timeout MINUTES'.` while the deployment itself keeps running without showing any timeout errors on the "Events" page.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been doing it at time of deployment for my environment and it works fine this way too.

```
eb deploy production-env --timeout 30
```

..and that gives me 30 minutes.