# Elastic beanstalk react application docker container launch issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to host a react application using docker on AWS elastic beanstalk. Application is working on local, also i tried to create a local docker image and run it, it works fine. **But while hosting same by uploading code as zip using AWS console, EB instance goes in "no data" or "invalid state", post that not able to do anything on that instance, can't even get logs out**. any suggestion would help.

It's a simple react app.

DockerFile content:

```
FROM node:13.13

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

start command in package

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was related to timeout, post timeout i was unable to anything from AWS console as the environment was going into "Invalid State". Though on EB UI/Cloudwath/Cloudformation logs gave nothing related to it, adding timeout config in *".ebextensions/timeout.config"* as

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000
```

Resolved the issue.

Reference: [Timeout Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557874/elastic-beanstalk-deployment-taking-longer-than-timeout-period-how-do-i-increas/25558805#25558805)