# Deployment fails on AWS Elastic Beanstalk docker environment due to build timeout - how can I increase the timeout for a Next.js app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to specify or increase docker build timeout on AWS Elastic Beanstalk docker environment?

AWS elastic beanstalk provides a default timeout of 300 seconds for docker environment and the application deployment fails if the docker image build time exceeds this value. I am trying to build a next.js app and with necessary optimisations in place the build time exceeds 300 seconds.

As recommended by few other Stack Overflow answers, I tried setting the command timeout value to be 600 seconds in the elastic beanstalk environment's configuration (**Rolling updates and deployments** -> **Deployment preferences**) but this does not help. The deployment still fails with a timeout error after 300 seconds.

[Command timeout option in beanstalk environment configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCAcm.png)

Comment: Did you try answers to this question :-  [Elastic beanstalk deployment taking longer than timeout period, how do I increase timeout period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557874/elastic-beanstalk-deployment-taking-longer-than-timeout-period-how-do-i-increas)